# Weird differentiation formula explanation

Tags: control-theory

I stumbled upon the following formula in a systems control textbook :

$$ s\left(\overline{x}^{(n-1)},t\right)=\left(\frac{d}{dt}+\lambda\right)^{(n-1)} e(t) \in R$$

where $\overline{x}^{(n-1)}=[x\ \dot{x} \dots x^{(n-1)} ]^T$

The textbook states that the derivative of this function wrt time is :
$$ \dot{s}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} \lambda^k e^{(n-k)} \in R$$

Can anyone understand how this is done?

Comment: I dreamed a dream in time gone by.... that controls systems people laid off a bit on the notation, for all that is good in this world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete bastardization of notation, but this is just the binomial theorem. In general:

$$(a+b)^m = \sum_{i=0}^m \begin{pmatrix} m \\ i \end{pmatrix} a^ib^{m-i}.$$

Plug in the differential operator for $a$, and $\lambda$ for $b$, and set your limits accordingly in the definition of $s$. Then, the derivative follows.

Comment: A followup remark: the binomial theorem holds in any commutative ring. So you can justify this by defining a ring of operators which act on $C^\infty$ functions, generated by $\mathbb{R} \cup \left \{ \frac{d}{dt} \right \}$. Most of the operations are defined in a completely obvious way, with the possible exception of $\frac{d}{dt} \cdot \frac{d}{dt} \equiv \frac{d^2}{dt^2}$. It isn't too hard to show that all the theorems this proves about operators on $C^\infty$ functions also hold when acting on $C^n$ functions if the derivatives only go up to order $n$.

Comment: @Ian I do controls. To controls guys, "ring" is what a telephone does. :)

Comment: The applied version: to prove the OP, it is enough to prove $\frac{d(cf)}{dt} = c \frac{df}{dt}$ and $\frac{d(f+g)}{dt} = \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{dg}{dt}$. :) (The version in several variables is harder: you wind up needing to show $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$ in addition to the above.)